# Check if an arraylist contains two strings

Tags: java, for-loop, java-stream

I have an pojo class like the one below

```
public CategoryModel {

public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

}
```

I have an arraylist created like the one below.

```
List<CategoryModel> variantCategoryModelList = new ArrayList<>();
CategoryModel cat1= new CategoryModel();
cat1.setName(TEST1);
CategoryModel cat2= new CategoryModel();
cat2.setName(TEST1);
list.add(cat1);
list.add(cat2);
```

I have to check, if the value "TEST1" & "TEST2" present in the list and return "true" if both values present in the "list" and I tried something like the one below, though my "list" has both the values, its returning false.Could you please help me check what I am doing wrong btw I am using JDK 11.

```
final Optional<CategoryModel> optionalData = variantCategoryModelList.stream().
                filter(valueData -> TEST1.equalsIgnoreCase(valueData.getName())
                        && TEST2.equalsIgnoreCase(valueData.getName())).findFirst();

        if(optionalData.isPresent()){
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Your first bit of code doesn't make sense. What is TEST1 and TEST2 in your second bit of code ?

Comment: If `list.get(0).getName` is a method you need `()`, if it is a variable, it is IMHO poorly named because it confuse us with getters and setters.

Comment: I'm not familiar with filters but I'm pretty sure that here, you check for `valueData.getName()` being equals to `TEST1` and `TEST2` at the same time, which doesn't seem possible neither what you want.

Comment: Hi Philippe ,have updated my code now.And yes I might be wrong in using the stream function, but i want both these strings to be checked in that List and return true if both present in the list.

Comment: You should get an error in this two lines `list.get(0).getName ="TEST1"; list.get(1).getName ="TEST2";`, you want a solution for this issue ?

Comment: I still don't get `list.get(n).getName = "something";` what is `getName` ? Why don't you just use a `for` loop and set booleans to true if you find your values ?

Comment: @YCF_L I'm wondering if `getName` isn't a variable, in this case he won't have compilation error.

Comment: Sorry Guys,my bad have removed the getName() as it was causing confusion.Kindly check now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set would be a more natural (and faster) data structure:

```
return variantCategoryModelList.stream()
                       .map(CategoryModel::getName)
                       .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                       .containsAll(Set.of("TEST1", "TEST2"));
```

Your problem was *and* (`&&`) instead of *or*.

So:

```
Set<String> soughtNames = Set.of("TEST1", "TEST2");
return variantCategoryModelList.stream()
                       .filter(cm -> soughtNames.contains(cm.getName()))
                       .distinct()
                       .count() == 2L;
```

*As @fps commented, `distinct()` is needed on a list to prevent ["Test1", "Test1"] to be accepted, or ["Test1", "Test1", "Test2"] failing.*

This is obviously inefficient as it will - having found 2 entries -, still walk to the end.

You want:

```
Set<String> soughtNames = Set.of("TEST1", "TEST2");
return soughtNames.stream()
    .allMatch(soughtName ->
         variantCategoryModelList.stream()
             .anyMatch(cm -> soughtName.equals(cm.getName()));
```

Or a bit retro-style:

```
return
    variantCategoryModelList.stream()
             .anyMatch(cm -> "TEST1".equals(cm.getName())) &&
    variantCategoryModelList.stream()
             .anyMatch(cm -> "TEST2".equals(cm.getName()));
```

Comment: @fps so right, a normal List would not do. Added `distinct()`.

Answer (score 6):

You could map your `CategoryModel` to name and collect to list of strings and call `List.containsAll` :

```
return variantCategoryModelList.stream()
                               .map(CategoryModel::getName)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList())
                               .containsAll(Arrays.asList("TEST1","TEST2"));
```

Comment: Nice solution; the only thing i'd suggest is that the OP wants it to be case insensitive so adding another `.map(String::toUpperCase)` to make everything uppercase would allow for that

Comment: It's better to use a `Set`

Comment: Besides, this solution doesn't *short-circuit* when both TEST1 and TEST2 have been found

Comment: @fps to short-circuit, just do the opposite: `return Stream.of("TEST1","TEST2") .allMatch(s -> variantCategoryModelList.stream().anyMatch(m -> m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(s)));` I’d say, it’s even simpler.

Comment: Had intended to edit my answer according to the comments, but as @JoppEggen has written a more detailed and better answer I leave it as it is and recommend the OP to accept JoppEggen's answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone and appreciate your time on this.As everyone suggested SET is going to be faster,I have used the same.Thanks again !!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it:

```
Set<String> set = Set.of("TEST1", "TEST2");
boolean result = list.stream()
    .filter(cat -> set.contains(cat.getName().toUpperCase())
    .distinct()
    .limit(2)
    .count() == 2L;
```

This streams the list of categories, then keeps only those categories whose name is either `TEST1` or `TEST2`. We then remove duplicates and stop after we've found two (already distinct) category names. This ensures *short-circuiting*. Finally, we check if we have exactly two elements at the end.